# MapInfo Pro 64-bit - 16.0.3 - Snap Frame to Guideline (unable to?)

Tags: mapinfo, layouts, snapping, 64bit, geodataframe

I am using MapInfo Pro 64-bit v16.0.3

In the layout, I want to snap my map frame to the guideline. I've noticed that when I create a rectangular box, this snaps to the guidelines once the edge is placed close to it.

When I try to do the same thing, but by pulling the edge of the 'frame box', it won't snap to the guideline.

The reason I am doing this is so that I can align the frame box to the exact specifications of my 'side panel' box (Holds Title, Legend, Scale, North Arrow, Disclaimer etc). I want the map frame and the side panel to be the same height (to line up exactly).

I've noticed that from 32bit to 64 bit they've removed the 'frame properties' that allow you to specify the X1, X2 and Y1, Y2. They instead only allow the top-left corner and then the width and height. Only problem is, when I change both my side-panel and map frame to be the same height exactly, it doesn't look that way in the layout.

Hence, If I can snap my frame box and rectangular (side panel) box to the guidelines, then I won't have to manually adjust the line.

If anyone knows another way of doing this, then I am all ears.

Answer (score 1):

When you have guide lines, the idea is that you can select one or more frames/elements in the layout and then align these left/right up/down to the nearest guideline.

You can find the Align option in the *Alignment* dropdown in the *Edit* group on the *LAYOUT* tab.

[image]

With MapInfo Pro 17.0, we have also added what we call Smart Guide which allows you to snap elements easily to the extent of other elements while moving or resizing these.